# Who left these eggs behind?

Tags: insects, brassicas

Found these on the leaves of my Brussels sprouts. Just wondering if I should remove them or leave them be.

[image: insect eggs]

Yes, snail damage present as well so I need to remove from under the leaves.

Answer (score 2):

They look like Moth eggs to me, and the larvae that turn into moths could be responsible for that damage. (Moth larvae:Moth::Caterpillar:Butterfly)

It's possible they're slug eggs. It's uncommon but not rare for snails to lay eggs on vegetation. http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/insects/slug-snail-eggs.htm

I'm going with moth, because most snail eggs are round and most snails lay eggs on the ground.

Comment: Makes sense that whoever left them there wanted them to take advantage of a free meal.  So, I'll be removing them.